# 1. Qt Application Program Deployment Issues in Ubuntu 18.04 Environment

Tags: qt, deployment, ubuntu-18.04

1. Deploy the Qt Application Program in Ubuntu 18.04 environment.
   Issue) Multimedia related video and camera related errors occur when installing and running the Qt application on Ubuntu 20.04.

- There is an error related to the Gstreamer, and it seems to have been caused by the Gstreamer version difference.
- - - - ubuntu 18.04(gstreamer 1.14) ubuntu 20.04(gstreamer 1.16)

Gstraimer is not compatible with each Ubuntu OS version, so how do I solve the above problem?
Or is there a good solution?

Comment: You probably want to build binaries on each system you support.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either:

1. Build your application against the versions available on the system where you deploy your application to.

So, to be specific in this case, you would need to build your Qt application against the dependencies available on Ubuntu 20.04. You may be able to obtain them on 18.04, but the easiest would be if you build your project on Ubuntu 20.04 in the first place.

2. Bundle up your application with the required dependencies and deploy them unto the system where you deploy your application to.

So, to be specific in this case, you could bundle up your application with dependencies from Ubuntu 18.04 and also deploy those to 20.04.